# Fullcalendar - change event color on select

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to set a default title and background color when selecting an event on fullcalendar. but the event is customized only after rendering it and not during its selection. Any idea? thx for your help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    navLinks: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end) {
      var eventData;
      eventData = {
        title: 'unavailable',
        start: start,
        end: end,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      };
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable: true,
  });

});
```

[image]

This is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juoh4ksz/)

Comment: "the event is customized only after rendering it and not during its selection. " That's the documented behaviour. The colour used for the selection is completely unrelated to the colour you define in the data of the newly created event, which is then rendered to the calendar. These two things are not the same. Your code is doing exactly what you told it to, correctly. Bear in mind that a selection does not have to result in a created event. The colour you're giving is for the event that you decided to create.

Comment: Also, by the time the "select" callback runs, it's trivially obvious to realise that the selection by dragging has already happened and been completed by the user (otherwise you wouldn't know the start/end times, plus you can realise this just by watching your program), so it's not even logical to expect that setting a colour at this time would affect the colour of something which was created in the past - so I'm unsure why you even thought it would be likely to do that?

Comment: There's no option in fullCalendar to set the colour that's used for this AFAIK, so you can just modify the fullCalendar CSS file directly in order to change it. If you examine the element representing the selection using your browser's developer tools, you can see what CSS rules are used to define its colours, and then go and modify those in the file. Of course if it turns out that fullCalendar is using code to define / create that, you'll have to modify the relevant JS instead.

Comment: @ADyson Thx for your answer, the solution was indeed to override the style of the .fc-event class